# When does Chrome pass a value other then 0 to the native messaging host for --parent-window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am developing a Chrome extension on windows. It also has a native messaging host. The argument passed to the host named --parent-window is in my case always 0.

[According to the Native Messaging Protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol) it says

> On Windows, the native messaging host is also passed a command line
>   argument with a handle to the calling chrome native window:
>   --parent-window=. This lets the native messaging host create native UI windows that are correctly focused.

I open my port for native messaging in the background JS. My understanding is that you cannot use this API in content.

[This Chromium Bug appears to be my issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=354597) but it was closed as a won't fix.

So when or in what circumstances does Chrome send something useful with the --parent-window?

Further on May 7 the writer who I assume knows a bit about chromium says

> Haven't tried it, but could you open your native messaging port in a
>   content script instead? Sounds like the --parent-window arg might be
>   useful in that case.

What does he mean and how do I do this?

Comment: Walking the call hierarchy in the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/messaging/native_process_launcher.cc?l=275&rcl=f20607c5) seems to indicate HWND is indeed passed only when connecting from a visible window/tab so you can open a new tab or window that points to a html file in your extension with a js file that talks to the native host - that is if Chrome won't perform connectNative() from a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), which is what the developer suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I am non the wiser about what you mean. Where exactly are you suggesting to call chrome.runtime.connectNative and when?

Comment: Ugh, elaborating would amount to posting a real answer. Hopefully someone else provides an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. In short it does not work as you would expect if you are a windows developer. Possibly comment 2 helps from the "Wont Fix" issue on Chromium.

[Comment 2 seems to explain when it might work.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=354597#c2)

> If you are using Native Messaging
>   (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging),
>   it would seem like the --parent-window command line parameter would
>   provide a solution.  Unfortunately, zero is passed for the parent
>   window if the native messaging connection is made from a background
>   page and (apparently) the HWND of a transient popup window is passed
>   if the native messaging connection is made from a browser action
>   popup.  And I am not allowed to call chrome.runtime.connectNative()
>   from a content script.  Therefore, in my extension at least,
>   --parent-window is not helpful.

My solution is immediately after

```
port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('myspecial.host.application');
```

I then use the following;

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tab) {
        console.log(tab[0].title);
        port.postMessage({ MessageType: 'chromeTitle', Message: tab[0].title });
    });
```

In your host if you add to this titel " - Google Chrome" then you can call FindWindowEX with the class "Chrome_WidgetWin_1" and the title to get the main handle of Google.